# Python Writing a XML Child Element Without Namespace

Tags: python-2.7, namespaces

I read multiple threads before posting about xml namespace, but still having issue with writing child xml element without namespace in a file.

Even though I mentioned registered namespace as empty before parsing/reading the file, "findall" not returning any elements. I verified the namespace present in code and xml file, also printed on root.tag.

If I completely remove the xmlns from  tag, code is working, but I wanted to read the xml file without namespace and write into file without namespace. Could you please let me know the mistake I m doing here ?

This is the code I tried.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
ET.register_namespace("","urn:iso:2012.tech.xsd.001.04") ##Making sure parse a xml file without namespace
tree = ET.parse("sample.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

print("%s : %s"%(root.tag, root.attrib))
out_handle = open("customer_header.xml","ab")

for elt in root.iter():
    all_ntry = elt.findall('Customer') ## Not returning all Customer elements, even though ET.register_namespace('',uri) mentioned before parsing
    for ele in all_ntry:
         print("Customer Block Found:%s"%ele)
         ele_tree = ET.ElementTree(ele)
         ele_tree.write(out_handle)
```

XML File(sample.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.company.org/2000/instance"
      xmlns="urn:iso:2012.tech.xsd.001.04">
     <BackToCustomer>
       <CustGrup>
          <Mid>000002</Mid>
          <Date>2017-09-24T00:54:26</Date>
          <Info>TEST</Info>
       </CustGrup>
  <Batch>
     <Id>12345678</Id>
     <Date>2017-09-22T13:54:26</Date>
     <ListInfo>
     <Id>
        <Othr>
          <Id>TEST_ListInfo</Id>
        </Othr>
     </Id>
    </ListInfo>
      <Details>
         <Total>
            <Count>5</Count>
            <Amt>25.80</Amt>
         </Total>
      </Details>
     <Customer>
        <CustomerRef>ABC123</CustomerRef>
      </Customer>
     <Customer>
        <CustomerRef>XYZ123</CustomerRef>
     </Customer>
  </Batch>
  </BackToCustomer>
 </Document>
```

I need to write a file only Customer element without namespace.

.